# Foreign key as primary key in EF Code First?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

I need to map a relationship between 3 domain models in my domain, where as one of the domain models is the aggregate root of the relationship model.

```
public class Entity1 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SuperEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // bounded context for relationship classes
}
```

The relationship entity should look like this

```
public class Relationship {
    public int RelationshipId { get; set; }
    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

Following this, the super entity should simply look like this:

```
public class SuperEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

Now, one possibility to map this is to make the relationship a unique entity with it's own key and both entities inside the relationship unique indexes. But then the key only serves "for key purposes" without any meaningful value. Desireable would be a relationship table like this:

```
Table_Relationships
                  [  SuperEntity_Id // Foreign-key to SuperEntity
  PrimaryKey      [  Entity1_Id // Foreign-key to Entity1
                  [  Entity2_Id // Foreign-key to Entity2
```

Meaning that the primary key of Table_Relationships would be SuperEntity_Id+Entity1_Id+Entity2_Id.

Is it possible to map this in EF Code First?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20MSDN))? It's clear way to define complex primary key in domain model classes.